# Getting error linker command failed with exit code in NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ndk-build

Here is my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Prebuild_usb1.0
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libusb-1.0.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Prebuild_ftrScanAPI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libftrScanAPI.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Prebuild_ftrAnsiSDK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libftrAnsiSDK.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ftrAnsiSDKAndroidJni
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__ANDROID_API__

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ftrAnsiSDKAndroidJni.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := Prebuild_usb1.0 Prebuild_ftrScanAPI 
Prebuild_ftrAnsiSDK
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**And my Application.mk looks like**

```
APP_ABI=armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

I am getting error when i build apk

> Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And sometime studio throws **warning: '__ANDROID_API__' macro redefined**

Here is exception

> Execution failed for task ':androidHelper:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\waqas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Androidprojects\androidstudiolatestzongsourceready\POSApp_AV06_STC_BVS\androidHelper\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\Androidprojects\androidstudiolatestzongsourceready\POSApp_AV06_STC_BVS\androidHelper\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=mips NDK_ALL_ABIS=mips NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-17 NDK_OUT=D:/Androidprojects/androidstudiolatestzongsourceready/POSApp_AV06_STC_BVS/androidHelper/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Androidprojects\androidstudiolatestzongsourceready\POSApp_AV06_STC_BVS\androidHelper\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib D:/Androidprojects/androidstudiolatestzongsourceready/POSApp_AV06_STC_BVS/androidHelper/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips/libftrAnsiSDKAndroidJni.so}
>   [mips] Compile++      : ftrAnsiSDKAndroidJni <= ftrAnsiSDKAndroidJni.cpp
>   In file included from :333:
>   :4:9: warning: '**ANDROID_API**' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
>
> ## define **ANDROID_API** 17
>
> ```
>     ^
> ```
>
> :3:9: note: previous definition is here
>
> ## define **ANDROID_API** 1

```
    ^
```

> 1 warning generated.
>   [mips] SharedLibrary  : libftrAnsiSDKAndroidJni.so
>   D:/Androidprojects/androidstudiolatestzongsourceready/POSApp_AV06_STC_BVS/androidHelper/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips/libusb-1.0.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
>   clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make:[D:/Androidprojects/androidstudiolatestzongsourceready/POSApp_AV06_STC_BVS/androidHelper/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/mips/libftrAnsiSDKAndroidJni.so] Error 1

Comment: Your observation is correct. The recent released of Android NDK define `__ANDROID_API__` to point to the platform level (normally, it is derived from `APP_PLATFORM` parameter for **ndk-build**). Why do you add this flag in your **Android.mk**?

Comment: Actually This is my very old project and i shifted to Android studio so i stuck here and can't find any solution.

Comment: Your script expects 3 prebuilt libraries: Prebuild_usb1.0 Prebuild_ftrScanAPI Prebuild_ftrAnsiSDK, but you only define one

Comment: I update my question please review it.

Comment: First, remove the line `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__ANDROID_API__` from your Android,mk; second, if you use integrated ndk-build in Android Studio, add [abiFilters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604243/192373) to **build.gradle** because APP_ABI is ignored.