# set Application.mk path in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, ndk-build

How to config path for **Appliction.mk** in **build.gradle**? I have several **Application.mk** files, like **Application1.mk**, **Application2.mk**, **Application3.mk**, I would like to let **Application.mk** point to different file accoring to my need. The following code snippet sets path for **Android.mk**, is there a similar way for **Application.mk**? In command line, the GNU make variable *NDK_APPLICATION_MK* can be used to set **Application.mk**, but how to do this in **build.gradle**?

```
    externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'jni/Android.mk'
    }
```

Comment: `android { externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild { arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=foo/bar/Application3.mk" } } }`

Comment: It's important to remember that gradle always overrides **APP_ABI**, so don't trust the setting you have in **ApplicationXX.mk**; add **abiFIlters** to your **build.gradle**.

Comment: @Michael It seems ndkBuild doesn't have arguments option.

Comment: @AlexCohn I have found this, thank you anyway.

Comment: @RobertLi: Right, I mistakenly indicated the `externalNativeBuild` directly under `android {}`. `ndkBuild` _will_ have an `arguments` property if the `externalNativeBuild` block is inside e.g. `defaultConfig {}` or inside a `buildType` or `productFlavor`.

Comment: re: APP_ABI, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603295/app-abi-ignored

Comment: @Michael it was a crazy idea to give two completely different DSLs same names: [externalNativeBuild](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension:externalNativeBuild) *vs* [externalNativeBuildOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:externalNativeBuild)